# Fastest way to convert data frame to a list of comma-separated strings

Tags: arrays, r, performance, dataframe, type-conversion

I have a data frame holding name of municipalities and name of states. It looks like this:

```
 my.df <- structure(list(Location = c("Abatiá", "Adrianópolis", "Agudos do Sul", 
"Almirante Tamandaré", "Altamira do Paraná", "Altônia"), State = c("PR", 
"PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR")), .Names = c("Location", "State"
), row.names = 0:5, class = "data.frame")
```

What I need to do is to convert this data frame to an array. The expected output would be something like:

```
my.array$PR
Abatiá, PR
Adrianópolis, PR
Agudos do Sul, PR
...

my.array$RS
Vitória das Missões, RS
Westfalia, RS
Xangri-lá, RS
...
```

and so on.

How can I get there?

My actual data set has about 10k rows, so a fast solution would perhaps be desirable over legibility. Thanks!

Comment: can you paste `dput(head(data)` (with `data` your data.frame)?

Comment: Yep, I edited the OP to show a little bit of my data.

Comment: I don't see any `RS` in the data

Comment: output doesn't seems to be an array but list of character(?), please edit question title if you are not looking for array result.

Comment: 10k rows isn't really that large for R so consider prioritizing readability!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should get you what you want.

```
df = data.frame("location" = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"), "state" = c("pr", "pr", "pr", "rs", "rs", "rs"), stringsAsFactors=F)
my.array = lapply(unique(df$state), function(x) paste(df$location[df$state == x], df$state[df$state == x], sep=", "))
names(my.array) = unique(df$state)
my.array$pr
# [1] "a, pr" "b, pr", "c, pr"
```

I simplified the values in `df`, but the point remains the same.

Comment: This produced exactly what I expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

because you want a list-like result (i.e., that you can index with `$`), use `split` on `State`. It will naturally produce a list with `State`s as names

*One* way to do it is to split first

```
split_df <- split(my.df, my.df$State)
my.array <- sapply(names(split_df), function(name) 
                               paste(split_df[[name]][["Location"]],
                                     ", ", name, sep=""), 
                    USE.NAMES = TRUE)
```

A *second* way to use split (which, after thinking more about your problem, seems more elegant) is to split after the location, state pairs directly

```
# First, create a new vector (array) of location, state pairs
# use apply(X, 1, FUN) which works row-wise along X
# and for each row, paste it together
location_state <- apply(my.df,
                        1,
                        function(r) paste(r["Location"],
                                          r["State"],
                                          sep=', '))
#Second, split that vector, using State
split(location_state, my.df$State)
```

**Example data**

```
states <- sapply(1:100, function(pass) paste0(sample(LETTERS, 2), collapse=""))
my.df <- data.frame(State=sample(states, 10000, replace=TRUE),
                 Location=sapply(1:1e4, function(pass) paste0(sample(letters, 5),
                                                         collapse="")), 
                    stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2):

how about using Reduce?

```
Reduce(function(...) paste(..., sep=", "), my.df)
```

---

EDIT: update benchmarking with @thelatemail suggestion

```
#for your  benchmarking using 1 million rows
library(rbenchmark)
df <- data.frame(X=rnorm(1e6), Y=rnorm(1e6))
benchmark(M1=Reduce(function(...) paste(..., sep=", "), df),
    M2=do.call(paste, c(df, sep=", ")))

##test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
##1   M1           10   68.60    1.219     68.55     0.00         NA        NA
##2   M2           10   56.28    1.000     56.22     0.07         NA        NA
```

do.call(paste, c(df, sep=", ")) is certainly faster!

Comment: Or `do.call(paste, c(my.df,sep=", ") )` again.

Comment: the `df` produced using `rnorm(1e6)` isn't a great benchmark for this problem: `State` implies there are few values, repeated often

Comment: Maybe `states <- sapply(1:100, function(pass) paste0(sample(LETTERS, 2), collapse=""))` then `df <- data.frame(State=sample(states, 10000, replace=TRUE), Loc=sapply(1:1e4, function(pass) paste0(sample(letters, 5), collapse="")))`